# What is Buffer Geometry of three.js?

Tags: three.js

The explanation presented in the three.js documentation about the command BufferGeometry is quite hard to understand to me.

[image: BufferGeometry]

It says..

> BufferGeometry is a  representation of mesh, line, or point geometry.
> Includes vertex positions, face indices, normals, colors, UVs, and
> custom attributes within buffers, reducing the cost of passing all
> this data to the GPU.

I didn't quite understand what those sentences meant.

What is the purpose of BufferGeometry? How do you visualize BufferGeometry in real life?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An instance of this class holds the geometry data intended for rendering.

If you want to visualize these data, you have to define a material and the type of 3D object (mesh, lines or points). The code example of the documentation page shows the respective JavaScript statements.

Comment: You mean....the BufferGeometry is like a little renderer in itself? Is the BufferGeometry is like a scratch paper where you draw your first drawing draft before you draw in the painting canvas for real?

Comment: No. It's more like a data structure just holding data.

Comment: hmmmm....I still don't quite understood it. I'll just accept your answer. All I know is BufferGeometry is useless in itself but it is used in conjunction with other commands. BufferGeometry is like a small memory who saves results from prior operations like arrays.